# Axios POST -> AWS HTTP API -> AWS Lambda getting the browser error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: aws-lambda, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

**What is happening:**

I have a React app that is using Axios to hit an AWS HTTP API (API Gateway) which then hits an AWS Lambda in order to interact with an AWS DocumentDB. Axios GET works just fine.

When I do a POST with Axios, I am met with the following error in the browser console: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my_endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**What I have tried:**

I have read a few stack overflow posts as well as some AWS API/CORS documentation. This has informed me about the preflight OPTIONS request, so I have added matching OPTIONS routes for my endpoints in my HTTP API and handled the OPTIONS routes in the Lambda with the following response:

```
 {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
                    }
                }
```

I have tried many variations of this response, with different combinations of headers. I have also tried adding the headers in the response for EVERY route, not just the OPTIONS routes.

Additionally, I have configured my HTTP API in AWS to allow all origins (`*`) and all methods (`*`), as well as included all the headers in the allows headers section.

Answer (score 0):

Could not solve this issue using AWS HTTP API, switched to REST API and followed all of the major advice (enable cors, add the correct origin header to lambda response)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).